# Is there a way to have git silently add all changes in a directory?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I do most work in IntelliJ, and Jetbrains recommend that the IDE's config directory `.idea` be kept in VCS.  The annoyance is that this directory contains many files (e.g. an XML file for every maven dependency) and often I'll change some dependencies in a leiningen project/change some IDE settings, tidy things up, do a few commits, then sometime after there'll be a small mountain of changes in `.idea`.

It's not a massive hardship to manage this with amended commits etc but I'd really rather not think about it - these are support files only, and the project is no less valid without them.  In a nutshell I want them in git for backup purposes - their version history is almost completely redundant (for me, anyway.)

Is there a way to have git silently and blindly add these all these files whenever it gets the chance, almost like the inverse of `.gitignore`?  In other words changes only in `.idea` would show up as a clean working tree, but they'd get committed at the next commit?

I'm fairly sure this is a Bad Idea™, but git's a complex beast and I wouldn't be surprised if some mechanism existed.

Comment: It's a pretty bad idea (?) to commit noise like that to your project. One problem it'll cause is whenever you switch branches the contents of that folder changes. If you _do_ want to version control/backup that folder - make it a seperate repo i.e. `cd .idea; git init; git add *; git commit -m "initial commit"`

Comment: Do you use Maven? If yes, you certainly do not need to keep `.idea` under version control.

Comment: @NickVolynkin I'm not sure how necessary it is but I know it stores other IDE settings beyond dependencies.  It is official Jetbrains advice that `.idea` be kept under VCS.

Comment: @AD7six As I said, it's what Jetbrains recommend Idea users do.  A separate repo could do the trick though, thanks.

Comment: @SLD yes, read it just now.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably added the entire `.idea` folder to Git, which is a Bad Idea™, as some of those files contain user-specific settings, like `workspace.xml`.

[The standing recommendation](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23393067) from IntelliJ is to omit select files depending on what project structure you're using.

- If you're using the `.idea` folder, omit `workspace.xml` and `tasks.xml` in your `.gitignore`

  ```
  .idea/workspace.xml
  .idea/tasks.xml
  ```
- If you're using the legacy `.iml`, `.ipr`, and `.iws` files, omit `.iws` in your `.gitignore`:

  ```
  *.iws
  ```

After that's done, you'll want to remove them from the repository

```
git rm --cached .idea/workspace.xml .idea/tasks.xml
```

or

```
git rm --cached *.iws
```

You should notice Git wanting to add changes to these files a lot less often.

---

The best standing advice I have for you is to *not* use this to bootstrap a project; while you can, there are better choices in other dependency management schemes such as Gradle and Maven which IDEA will work well with.

Comment: I support the recommendation of Gradle and Maven.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Maybe I should clarify: I'm definitely *not* using this to bootstrap anything - that's handled with a proper tool (leiningen). I'm just trying to follow Jetbrains' advice of keeping it in VCS without having the admittedly minor inconvenience of dealing with all the automatic changes at seemingly random points.